# Why the following code prints garbage values for input strings greater than 128 bytes?

Tags: c++11, vector

This is a  [problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/CHRL2)  of codechef that I recently came across. The answer seems to be right for every test case where the value of input string is less than 128 bytes as it is passing [a couple of test cases](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/8823349). For every value greater than 128 bytes it is printing out a large value which seems to be a garbage value.

```
std::string str;
std::cin>>str;
vector<pair<char,int>> v;
v.push_back(make_pair('C',0));
v.push_back(make_pair('H',0));
v.push_back(make_pair('E',0));
v.push_back(make_pair('F',0));
int i=0;
while(1)
{
    if(str[i]=='C')
        v['C'].second++;
    else if (str[i]=='H')
    {
        v['H'].second++;
        v['C'].second--;
    }
    else if (str[i]=='E')
    {
        v['E'].second++;
        v['C'].second--;
    }
    else if (str[i]=='F')
        v['F'].second++;
    else
        break;
    i++;
```

Even enclosing the same code within

```
/*reading the string values from a file and not console*/
std::string input;
std::ifstream infile("input.txt");
while(getline(infile,input)) 
{
    istringstream in(input);
    string str;
    in>>str;
    /* above code goes here */
}
```

generates the same result. I am not looking for any solution(s) or hint(s) to get to the right answer as I want to test the correctness of my algorithm. But I want to know why this happens as I am new to `vector` containers`.

-Regards.

Comment: `v['C']` is equivalent to `v[67]` because the `char` `'C'` is type promoted to `size_type` (which is the parameter of `vector::operator[]()`. Your vector does not have that many members, thus you are accessing uninitialized memory. What where you trying to do?

Comment: @dhke I was thinking about using a key value pair like we do in popular languages such as python or javascript but little did I know about `std::map` . So I thought of keying the value 'C' with an integer zero. Whenever the 'C' occurs the integer assocaited with 'C' in this case v[67] will increment to one.

Comment: @dhke i tried to understand the concept of variable promotion and casting thank you for the insight .. :)  Just one more Question that I can't figure it out ie why 128 Bytes ? Does the vector also has the concept of byte padding like we have in structs ?

Comment: 128 bytes is probably the allocation unit by used by the memory allocator. You can check by printing the value of `v.capacity()` how much room there really is in the vector. The exact number is most likely different depending on operating system, compiler, standard library, processor, etc. pp. The behavior is *specified to be undefined* so there's not use trying to track the problem down.

Comment: @dhke thankyou :) -regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(str[i]=='C')
        v['C'].second++;
```

You're modifying v[67]

... which is not contained in your vector, and thus either invalid memory or uninitialized

Comment: I tried to declare vector<pair<char,int>> v; globally but no help. @LudwigSchulze

Comment: If your accessing index 67 in a vector that contains only 4 entries, bad things will happen. Where that vector is defined has no influence on that.

Comment: @LudwigSchulze Just out of curiosity is v['C'-65] a good practice ?

Comment: Not sure for what purpose. Maybe related: To get the integer value of digits: char d = ...; if (d>='0' && d<='9') { int digit_value = d-'0'; do_something_with(digit_value);} I would consider this standard practice.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to use a `vector` as an associative array. There is already such a structure in C++: a `std::map`. Use that instead.

Comment: Thank you. Little did I know about `std::map` and you quite pin pointedly pointed out the need of a key value pair that I am trying to use :) :) - thank you :) :)

Answer (score 0):

With using this `v['C']` you actually access the 67th (if 'A' is 65 from ASCII) element of a container having only 4 items. Depending on compiler and mode (debug vs release) you get undefined behavior for the code.

What you probably wanted to use was map i.e. `map<char,int> v;` instead of `vector<pair<char,int>> v;` and simple `v['C']++;` instead of  `v['C'].second++;`